# progress - syntax to modify FIELD

Tags: database, openedge, progress-db

I added field to Progress databyse by

```
ADD FIELD filedName on TABLEName...
```

and now I want to change/modify this field (PRECISION or FORMAT or something else...)

What syntax will be correct ? I tried like this:

- `UPDATE FIELD`
- `MODIFY FIELD`
- `ALTER FIELD`

I tried aldo sql notation: `alter table`
but nothing works.

Could You help me please with syntax to modify field ?

Comment: What version of Progress?  Are you using the 4gl engine?  Or are you using an external sql92 tool?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the 4GL engine (you are using _progres or prowin32 to start a session) then you want to use the "data dictionary" tool to create DDL.  You run "dict.p" to access that tool.  i.e.:  _progres dbName -p dict.p

This will allow you to create tables, define fields and indexes etc.  If you want to export the definitions you use the "admin" sub-menu to dump a ".df" file.  You can manually edit the output but you need to know what you are doing.  It is mostly obvious but it is not documented or supported.

Do NOT imagine that using SQL from within a 4GL session will work.  It will not.  The 4GL engine internally supports a very limited subset of sql-89.  It is mostly there as a marketing ploy.  There is nothing but pain and agony down that road.  Don't go there.  If you are using _progres or prowin32 you are using the 4gl engine.

If you are using SQL92 externally (via sqlexp or some other 3rd party SQL tool that uses an ODBC or JDBC connection) then normal SQL stuff should work but you might want to spend some quality time with the documentation to understand the areas where OpenEdge differs from Oracle or Microsoft or whatever sql dialect you are used to.

Comment: -infinity for the Data Dictionary, it looks like a tool they dig up from the late 70's...

Answer (score 1):

Tom, thanks for Your answer.

I use OpenEdge Release 10.1A02 on Linux.

I can make a dump.df file and I can also add new table from file (similar df).
But why I cant modify any added fields ? Ofcorse i can use "p" editor and  do it manually from menu Tools/Data Editor/Schema  and add new table but it's risky if I tell database administrators to do it manually on each enviroment (specially on production).

if exists syntax:
ADD FIELD filedName on TABLEName...
why there is no
Modify FIELD filedName on TABLEName...          ?

Bartek.

Comment: You can create or modify a .df file with an editor or even build one with a program.  But the syntax is undocumented - you're on your own to try to figure it out.  Some stuff is easy and obvious.  Other bits not so much.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case - here are some working examples of *.df* files in OE 11.3 (could be they are valid in other versions too):

- Rename column:

  `RENAME FIELD "OldName" OF "TableName" TO "NewName"`
- Other properties:

  `UPDATE FIELD "FieldName" OF "TableName"`

  `FORMAT "Yes/No"`

  `LABEL "Label"`

  `VALMSG "Validation message..."`

Of course the database must be shut down first (apply those changes in single-user mode).